# Can't locate div element - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am unable to locate a div element using the css_selector. Please find my code below.

```
driver = wb.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.jumia.com.ng/")

driver.maximize_window() #//For maximizing window
driver.implicitly_wait(20) #//gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds



#WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'star _s')))
#driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name('star _s'))






#selecting phones and tablets

clickObj = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a[4]/span").click()



#selecting mobile phones only

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div/article[1]/a[2]").click()


#selecting smartphones only

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div/article[1]/a[2]").click()


#selecting android phones only

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div/article[1]/a[1]").click()



product_info = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.info")

product_name = list()
price = list()
rating = list()

for info in product_info:
    #print(info.find_elements_by_class_name("rev")
    
    product_name.append(info.find_element_by_css_selector("h3.name").text)
    rating.append(info.find_element_by_css_selector("div.rev").text)
    price.append(info.find_element_by_css_selector("div.prc").text)
    #rating.append(info.find_element_by_class_name("rev").text)
    
data = {"product_name":product_name, "rating":rating, "price":price}
df_product = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

It returns the below error despite the presence of an element such as "rev":

**NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: div.rev**

This is the [link](https://www.jumia.com.ng/android-phones/) to the site https://www.jumia.com.ng/android-phones/

Please assist. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to not considering space between tag name and class name in *find_elements_by_css_selector* function.

```
product_info = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div .info")
```

In addition, the type of *product_info* variable is *<class 'list'>*. Thus, it is not possible to apply the functions or methods of *Selenium* library. To fill other lists, you have to use *product_info.text* and apply for loop for it.

Refer to below code as the sample one:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.jumia.com.ng/android-phones/")
driver.maximize_window() #//For maximizing window

#selecting android phones only
product_info = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div .info")

for info in product_info:
    try:
        print(info.text)    
    except:
        break

driver.close()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried the first solution but it was giving me the "InvalidSelectorException" error. Could you please clarify what you mean by the space?

Comment: You wrote `div.info` without any space between  *div* and *.info* and it causes an error.

Comment: I have tried it with the space and I still get the "InvalidSelectorException" error

Comment: Thank you. Your sample code worked perfectly but it's not exactly what I want. I want to separate product name, price & review into diff columns of a df